# Laravel - Shared hosting that supports Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, web-hosting

I'm looking for shared hosting like Hostgator but supports laravel out of the box.

Comment: I expect they all do - just ensure the version of PHP is recent enough for the version of Laravel you are using. I can't imagine Laravel would have been engineered not to work on common LAMP hosting. Note that questions seeking hosting/tutorial/language/framework/etc recommendations are off-topic, as historically they have attracted spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A2 Hosting](http://a2hosting.com) is a shared hosting platform that supports Laravel installed right out of the box. Click [here](https://www.a2hosting.com/laravel-hosting) to see their Laravel support.

Comment: I am not trying to advertise here, nor am I affiliated with the hosting company I have listed. I am merely offering an answer to his question.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think you were _actually_ spamming. But since the question is off-topic, it is often thought here that help is best kept to the comments section. It is one of the many Stack Overflow memes (there are a lot of them!).